# Get value from select Angular 8.2. ( FormBuilder )

Tags: angular

I want to take the "id" of a select I have with Angular 8.2

```
  <select (change)='changeProvider($event)' class="form-control" id="field_provider"
        name="provider" formControlName="providerId">
    <option [ngValue]="providerOption.id"
       *ngFor="let providerOption of providers; trackBy: trackById">
        {{ providerOption.indentifier }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

// Controller

```
changeProvider(event$: any): void {
    event$.target.value <-- "1: 5e450f7aa2aa82760cee469c"
```

I added "1:" at the beginning

"1: 5e450f7aa2aa82760cee469c" instead of "5e450f7aa2aa82760cee469c"

I don't know if it's an option I'm missing or what.

Because I don't see very elegant having to be removing "1:" from the string to make it work for me

Comment: use [value] instead of [ngValue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  you should use value:

```
<select (change)='changeProvider($event)' class="form-control" id="field_provider"
        name="provider" formControlName="providerId">
    <option *ngFor="let providerOption of providers; [value]="providerOption.id" trackBy: trackById">
        {{ providerOption.indentifier }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Selected Id, you can bind it to variable 
in ts

```
 selectedprovider = "";
  changeProvider(): void {
    alert(this.selectedprovider);
  }
```

in html add [(ngModel)]="selectedprovider"

```
  <select (change)='changeProvider()'  id="field_provider"
        #provider="ngModel"  name="provider" [(ngModel)]="selectedprovider">
  <option [ngValue]="providerOption.id"
          *ngFor="let providerOption of providers; trackBy: trackById">
    {{ providerOption.indentifier }}
  </option>
</select>
```